# How to create node project using npm init? Getting stuck at version

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-init

I am a newbie of nodejs, I am trying to a create node js project using *npm init* command but it stops at version. Can someone please help?

Below is error:

> Press ^C at any time to quit.
>   name: (node_init)
>   version: (1.0.0)

Comment: Did you hit the `Enter` key while the `version` input was prompted?

Comment: yes but nothing happens even ctrl+c not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an error in the newest version. You can use *npm init -f* as a workaround until it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make use of 
    `npm init --yes`
or 
    `npm init -y`

and npm initializes a project with the default package.json values, or

```
npm init -f
```

using --force

Reference: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init